# Checkin into facebook using NFC tags

Tags: facebook, nfc

I am working on my hobby project where i want to use NFC tags to check into facebook. Scenario is user will come to some location and will tap his mobile (containing facebook app) and it will be check into the location on facebook. I would really love your suggestions on this?

Comment: please do some research and tell us what you´ve found out on your own first.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to create a facebook app that will check you automatically just using a mobie browser (no native app has to be installed). However you need to create a facebook app for this and the checking users have to allow it to access their profile.